# Redux Framework: Page freezes on typing in Editor

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript

I am using Redux Framework.

I am facing an Issue with the editor in Theme Options of Redux Framework

Currently I have 103 editors in the options.

My Issue is that whenever I start typing something then whole page freezes and takes a lot of time to unfreeze.

When I reduce the amount of editors from 103 to 15 then It works perfectly but whenever I use too many editors (103) then It freezes.

I researched a lot from the internet about this but could not find any solution yet.

I'll appreciate for any contribution.

Comment: Im also using Redux in some projects but Im not sure what you mean by 103 _editors_. Could you clarify?

Comment: Your problem is as obvious as you describe - you have OVER ONE HUNDRED editors on the page! No wonder it's freezing. There is no "fix" other than to reduce the number of editor instances.

Comment: Yes but it should not freeze on type. It works normally before starting typing.
But when I start typing in any one of those editors then it stucks. why it stucks only on typing in one editor?

Comment: @N00b 103 are the total amount of editors which I used.

Comment: Editor like [this](https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/editor/)? Just out of curiosity.. Why does one need over 100 of these?! If you told us why you need so many editors, we could maybe suggest a better solution. I honestly can't think of situation where I needed 103 editors.

Comment: Actually we have a large website that need CMS to handle things easily. And we found this redux option as best choice.

Comment: I've got a very large website too which uses easily over 100 Redux options. Editor seems to be pretty heavy on performance, make sure that you choose _right field types_ considering options nature - dropdowns, radio buttons etc.

Comment: yes I have more than 100 options but this is happening only because of editor option